# Adding a horizontal scroll bar to window form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a window form which has many controls and I need to set horizontal scroll bar for width of the form. Moreover, I am displaying it as a child form to mdi parent and when I maximize the form, display is not proper. How can I set and bind horizontal scroll bar to form width so that it is scrollable.

Any type of help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set AutoScroll property of your form to true:

```
Form1.AutoScroll = true;
```

Comment: Setting above property to true just got me vertical scrolling working but I couldn't get access to horizantal scrolling.

Comment: well it shows scroll bars as needed. if your content's width is bigger than your form width you will get a horizontal scrollbar. if content height is bigger you will get a vertical scroll bar. if both are bigger you will get both scrollbars.

Comment: @KamalSubodh Please test with a simple form to see what I mean

Comment: Thanks, I understood it well and got corrected.